# How to squash commits that contain merge commits without re-resolving conflicts?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-squash

I've been working on a long running branch and I've been pulling another branch (develop) into my branch every so often. I've also been making small WIP (Work in Progress) commits as I go along. I'd like to rebase/squash all the WIP commits including the merge commits from develop branch and fast forward/update my branch to the present. However, some of the pulls from develop did have merge conflicts and this seems to be causing me a problem.

I tried `git rebase -i <hash>` and `git rebase --rebase-merges -i <hash>` but both times, Git asks me to re-resolve all the merge commits/conflicts (all the way back to a month ago, in this case) and doesn't seem to be smart enough to just "update" my branch with the present state of develop branch and squash all of my WIP commits. I don't want to re-resolve all the conflicts.

Is there a clean/easy way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `git reset --soft` for this, but note that this *loses the merge status*. Making a real (not squash) merge might be a better way to go. Doing that is a little more complicated. (If you don't need a merge, which you might not, then the easy, soft-reset-and-commit method is the way to go.)

Comment: @torek - Thanks! I guess I will be going with `git reset`. I was thinking that `rebase` would permit this. I guess not though. Thanks for the reply.